# mongodb push document inside array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql

I have a following collection:

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

Now if there's not document inside `instock` array with `warehouse` value `C` already, then I need to add a document with value `C`.

So I tried this with a `$push` operator:

```
db.inventory.updateMany(
    {"instock.warehouse": {$ne: "C"}},
    $push: {"instock": {"warehouse": "C", "qty": 04}}
)
```

this throws `unexpcted token expected: ","`

What's wrong here? Is this something to do with positional operator `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {"instock.warehouse": {$ne: "C"}},
  {$push: {"instock": {"warehouse": "C", "qty": 4}}}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bM1EPdULjaq)

Comment: Thanks... Also does $ positional operator matter here? I'm bit confused about that operatior.

Comment: No, `$` positional operator is for updating an item (that match a condition) in an array. On your case, you want to `$push` into an array (adding a new item), not to update one of its existing items